# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar nuevos correos entre 2 ficheros?

Tags: linux, unix

Tengo 2 ficheros que contienen cientos de correos y quisiera filtrar sólo los correos nuevos (Los que no aparezcan en ambos ficheros) Y quisiera saber si hay una forma fácil de hacerlo usando el terminal redirigiendo la salida a un archivo ejemplo `nuevosemails.txt`. Llevo rompiéndome la cabeza un buen rato...

Ejemplo con 2 archivos en muy pequeña escala (Se supone que voy a hacerlo a gran escala con miles de correos)

$ cat emails1.txt
`email@email.com
ejemplo@email.com
emailtest@test.com
prueba@123.net
ejemplo14@emailing.es`

$ cat emails2.txt
`ejemplo@email.com
filtrado@123456.org
email@email.com
emailtest@test.com
ejemplo14@emailing.es
prueba48@njp.net
prueba@123.net`

Bien... El archivo *emails2.txt* contiene `filtrado@123456.org` y `prueba48@njp.net` que *emails1.txt* no tiene. ¿Cómo podría extraer esos correos (Teniendo en cuenta que sería con miles de emails) de un modo simple?

El método que se me ocurre es hacer un script que seleccione las linea de un archivo con `sed` y que compruebe con `grep` en otro, con un bucle incrementando en +1 para que compruebe linea a linea, y si la búsqueda genera una variable de salida "1", con la variable que `sed` genera de la linea seleccionada, la redireccione a un archivo como puede ser >> *nuevosemails.txt*. Y así consigo filtrarlo. Esto se me ha ocurrido según escribía el ejemplo. Si álguien no tiene una mejor sugerencia, en cuento tenga un rato lo creo y me autorrespondo por si le pueda servir a alguien la ayuda en un futuro.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español @Heibol, te referís a como hacerlo mediante comandos en la terminal utilizando `bash` o algún lenguaje de `script`?

Comment: Hola, otra pregunta, ¿en que formato están los archivos? y ¿entre uno y otro archivo se encuentran ordenados o podrían aparecer en orden aleatorio?

Comment: @Alan Si, en bash con los comandos que suelen venir en casi toda distribución basada en GNU/Linux, pero si tengo que usar python, o perl me vale.

Los archivos estan en texto plano.

Comment: @Heibol Podrias editar la pregunta con un ejemplo de tu archivo, para que te podamos ayudar mejor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -F -f emails1.txt -v emails2.txt
```

- `grep [opciones] patrón [ficheros...]` muestra líneas que coinciden con un patrón
- `-F` trata los patrones a comprobar como cadenas de texto **F**ijas, no como expresiones regulares
- `-f fichero` Obtiene los patrones a comprobar de un **f**ichero
- `-v` in**v**ierte el sentido de la búsqueda, es decir, muestra las líneas que no coinciden.